# Is there a way to display links as footnotes in print media?

Tags: css

I know you can [put link URLs directly after the link itself](https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries), but is there a way to do that at the bottom of the page instead?

If I have a page that looks like this:

```
<p>Check <a href="http://example.com">here</a> and <a href="http://example.net">here</a> for more information.</p>
```

I can use the CSS trick above to make the print version look like this:

```
Check here (http://example.com) and here (http://example.net) for more information.
```

Is there a way to make it look like this instead?

```
Check here[1] and here[2] for more information.

[1] http://example.com
[2] http://example.net
```

Comment: You can add a print stylesheet where you can show/hide/change stuff as you normally do with media queries. Please see https://css-tricks.com/css-tricks-finally-gets-a-print-stylesheet/ and this https://davidwalsh.name/optimize-your-links-for-print-using-css-show-url. I think the David Walsh's article addresses what you want to achieve.

Comment: @roymckrank Both of those actually use the same trick I linked in the question, which puts the URL directly next to the link.  I was hoping to get something that would drop them to the bottom of the page instead.

Comment: I can number them using a combination of that trick and [css counters](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/numbering-with-css-counters/); just need to get the links to the bottom now.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of links you could achieve what you want. Let's assume there are three links in your section.

```css
section {
  counter-reset: links;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}

section a {
  counter-increment: links;
}

section a::after {
  content: "["counter(links)"]";
}

section a::before {
  content: " ["counter(links)"] "attr(href);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
    
section a:nth-of-type(1)::before {
  bottom: 2em;
}

section a:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  bottom: 1em;
}

section a:nth-of-type(3)::before {
  bottom: 0em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href="first.htm">Here's</a> your <a href="second.htm">text</a> containing <a href="third.htm">three links</a>.
</section>
```

Note: In long texts on multiple pages you may get unexpected results. But you could devide your text in multiple sections. And of course your css code increases with every new link...

Comment: This also only works if the `a`s are a direct child of the section, as if they are split across multiple `p`s within that section for instance, the `nth-of-type` values will reset.

Answer (score 0):

*I personally would do it this way.*

First create a hidden `ul` element at the bottom with an **id**.

```
<ul id="footnotes"></ul>
```

CSS

```
#footnotes {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Then give all `a` elements on the page an index manually.

```
<a href="https://google.com" data-index="1">My link</a>
<a href="https://amazon.com" data-index="2">My link</a>
<a href="https://spotify.com" data-index="3">My link</a>
```

Then show the footnotes element in print mode and attach its index behind.

```
@media print {
    a:after {
        content: "["attr(data-index)"]";
    }

    #footnotes {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Now iterate in JavaScript through all `a` elements on the page and show the link for each index.

```
const footNotes = document.getElementById('footnotes');
const links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = '[' + links[i].getAttribute('data-index') + '] ' + links[i].getAttribute('href');

    footNotes.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I know I can do it with javascript; just trying to figure out if I can do it with straight CSS.

Comment: I think it's not possible without JavaScript.